# Is using `innerHTML` the only way to create a `button` element in JavaScript with the `type` attribute?

Tags: javascript, button

I wanted to make a button with the following JavaScript...

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.type = 'button';
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('I am button'));
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

It works great, **except in IE7/8** (all I have tested so far).

> Message: `Object doesn't support this action`
>  Line: `185`
>   Char: `9`
>  Code: `0`
>  URI: `http://example.com/widget.js`

I found a workaround...

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<button type="button">I am button</button>';
```

That is, set `innerHTML` and let the browser do the parsing.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PRCLv/).

Is there any other way to get this to work in IE without setting the `innerHTML` property?

Comment: Does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/PHrpz/ ? (i have no IE)

Comment: @stewe Nope, it doesn't work in IE 7 or 8 (I used my Chrome IE Extension and it didn't work)

Comment: @Phil I added the error message. It seems IE *must* know the `type` attribute up front, or it has a problem.

Comment: @alex Looking at the article in Ray's answer, you could try `setAttribute()`

Comment: @Phil I didn't even think to check `setAttribute()`. It appears to work in IE7 + 8. Think it may be time to convert comment to answer :)

Comment: @alex Nah, give it to Cam or Ray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.newearthonline.co.uk/article/347) which you might have seen, the direct `createElement` DOM call in IE7/8 does not work with the `button` element, but it does work with `input`.

You may be right about `innerHTML` solutions (and the use of jQuery with HTML source, which is in spirit pretty much the same thing, IMHO) being the only approach.

Very strange about the DOM deficiency in IE7/8.  Very interesting find!

Comment: +1 I did not find that article (must of been using the wrong keywords).

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `.setAttribute()`? The following appears to work in IE 8 (didn't test in 7), Chrome, FF:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('type','button')
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('I am button'));
document.body.appendChild(button);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 Nice! So it does work, just without the direct assignment to the attribute via a JS property.  Does `button.setAttribute('type','submit')` work?  The article we are discussing seems to say no.  Interesting.

Answer (score -1):

Using `innerHTML` replaces everything in the element with what you specify.

jQuery `.append()` works in IE7/8: (and it is much easier)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<button type="button">I am a button</button');
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ne48/

Comment: The *jQuery way* is essentially using `innerHTML` too I believe.

Comment: @alex `.append()` is not the same as `innerHTML` Did you see my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ne48/)? I tested it in IE7 and 8 and it works.

Comment: @Nathan: Your append example does still use `innerHTML`. There is no other sensible way to create a DOM element from an HTML string.